# How to get list of cursor object from room dao access?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am trying to chnage my code to make use of room database APIs. For documents table I have defined Entity class `Document`, when I query `getAll()` it returns me all the document.

Now I have old implementation of Adapter which makes user of `Cursor` ( Its a `CursorAdapter` ). In my `DocumentDao` class I defined one method to get list of cursor objects. My Dao class as follows :

```
@Dao
public interface DocumentDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM documents")
    List<com.myapp.room.entity.Document> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM documents")
    List<Cursor> getCursorAll();
}
```

During compile time I am getting following error :

```
Error:(20, 18) error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
```

The official guide for [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) which states that :

> If your app's logic requires direct access to the return rows, you can
>   return a Cursor object from your queries, as shown in the following
>   code snippet:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE age > :minAge LIMIT 5")
    public Cursor loadRawUsersOlderThan(int minAge);
}
```

My question is do I need to write converter for this purpose ?

Comment: Updated documentation link (I can't edit the post due to the edit queue being full): https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-cursor

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're returning a `List<Cursor>` instead of a `Cursor`. Change:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM documents")
List<Cursor> getCursorAll();
```

for

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM documents")
Cursor getCursorAll();
```

Comment: Well I completely forgot Cursor itself has multiple object, I just need to iterate over them using cursor.moveToNext() :) I think I should delete my question ?

Comment: Just leave it. Anyone may make the same mistake ;)

Comment: now how to convert the Cursor's current record into a model object? I looked inside the _Impl.java, and the code is customized and not reusable